# How can I get better at DPS as a Ranger?

Tags: everquest-2

My 90 ranger is in full tier 2 PQ gear with the Mastercrafted Fabled bow (Bow of the Lost, I think). All of my ranged combat arts are Experts or Masters, and I have 277 AA.

In groups, I'm parsing second, sometimes third, after mages and other scouts. I know I should be higher on the parse, and occasionally in raids I get called out for not parsing higher.

Do you know some good tips & tricks on how to maximize my DPS as a ranger?

Comment: First is
1) Do you have your mythical Buff?
2) Whats ur multi attack at?
3) Whats ur aa line on the predator tree. I am a ranger from LCN and i can destroy any class anytime :)

Comment: 1) Yep. 2) Before the last patch, it was about 120%. 3) I have the pretty standard AA line down to PFT.

Answer (score 3):

You need 300 aa's explosive arrow consisting of 15% of your dps, make sure 10 points go straight to crit chance and crit bonus.
Also I suggest spike dps if you want to be made more valuable to raids stack your buffs and use your biggest recast off the bat always using both of your dots (arrow barrage, and bleed).

What's your casting order? Have you taken advantage of every single multi-attack adornment as well as piercing, crushing, etc.?